# MYSQL Automatic INSERT ID in a different table

Tags: mysql, indexing, phpmyadmin, relation

I am trying to learn some new things in MYSQL with PHPMyAdmin and I am wondering if the following thing is possible and how to get that to work. I'll try to explain it plain.

I have two tables
Table 1 = users & has
userID
username
etc.

Table 2 = users_permission & has
id
userID
is_admin

Now my idea was when I create record in table 1 by using an relation to table 2. It will automatically insert userID in Table 2 and create record based on default values. Is there someone who can help to get on track?

Comment: have you looked at adding a trigger to table1?

Comment: No I didn't and I created now an trigger with an insert after and in the values I have used new.userID which is an function in mysql I found. Which did the job I expected to be done. Thanks as I wasn't aware of triggers,yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make insertion for both tables seperately.

You first need to insert user into users table after that you need to insert into user permissions.

```
insert into users (userId, username) values( 1, 'JohnDoe');
insert into user_permission (id, userId, isAdmin) values (10, 1, 1);
```

---

For auto incremented ID column

```
insert into users (username) values('JohnDoe');
insert into user_permission (userId, isAdmin) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 1);
```

Comment: Alright so there is no other logic in MYSQL then creating a second query that will finish the job?

Comment: you can create stored procedure to provide atomic behavior. But inside that procedure you again need two different insert queries

Comment: But my userID is an auto increased number. So after my record created in table 1. I need to do an SELECT userID WHERE username = JohnDoe (UNIQUE). After that create an INSERT INTO users_permission (userID) values (userID). For some reason this sounds not clean enough.

Comment: That worked as well. I do think this way is more preferably than using triggers in the database right? As I can see the downside's of using triggers rather easy.